# Pass data between forms (event not triggered)

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing an application that passes gps data from a main form to a gps form at a constant interval (using a timer).

I've used the following tutorial to make a quick test:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17371/Passing-Data-between-Windows-Forms

However, when I start the code no event is triggered. First I got a nullpointer. after adding the following lines I got rid of it:

```
if (GpsUpdated != null)
{
    GpsUpdated(this, args);
}
```

**Main form code:**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    // add a delegate
    public delegate void GpsUpdateHandler(object sender, GpsUpdateEventArgs e);

    // add an event of the delegate type
    public event GpsUpdateHandler GpsUpdated;

    int lat = 1;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form_GPS form_gps = new Form_GPS();
        form_gps.Show();
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Timer Tick");
        // instance the event args and pass it each value
        GpsUpdateEventArgs args = new GpsUpdateEventArgs(lat);

        // raise the event with the updated arguments
        if (GpsUpdated != null)
        {
            GpsUpdated(this, args);
        }
    }
}

public class GpsUpdateEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private int lat;

    // class constructor
    public GpsUpdateEventArgs(int _lat)
    {
        this.lat = _lat;
    }

    // Properties - Viewable by each listener
    public int Lat
    {
        get
        {
            return lat;
        }
    }
}
```

**GPS form code:**

```
public partial class Form_GPS : Form
{
    public Form_GPS()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form_GPS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("GPS Form loaded");
        Form1 f = new Form1();

        // Add an event handler to update this form
        // when the ID form is updated (when
        // GPSUpdated fires).

        f.GpsUpdated += new Form1.GpsUpdateHandler(gps_updated);
    }

    // handles the event from Form1
    private void gps_updated(object sender,GpsUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Event fired");
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Lat.ToString());
    }
}
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance and with best regards.

Comment: Looks like you've got a bit of a loop here? `Form1` loads a `Form_GPS` which in turn loads a `Form1`

Comment: Ok I see. But how can I access the Form1 from where the event is triggered?

Comment: What might be best is to set up your GPS timer somewhere else, possibly a Singleton class or pass it into the constructor of the Forms, then you can hook up to the event handler there.

Answer (score 2):

You should pass an instance of `Form1` to your `Form_GPS` for it to work properly. See the following changes:

```
public partial class Form_GPS : Form
{
    public Form_GPS(Form1 owner)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        owner.GpsUpdated += new Form1.GpsUpdateHandler(gps_updated);
    }

    private void Form_GPS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("GPS Form loaded");
    }

    // handles the event from Form1
    private void gps_updated(object sender,GpsUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Event fired");
        Debug.WriteLine(e.Lat.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now you need to a small change in `Form1` as well:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Form_GPS form_gps = new Form_GPS(this);
    form_gps.Show();
    timer1.Enabled = true;
}
```

Notice how you pass an instance of `Form1` to `Form_GPS` in the constructor of `Form_GPS` using the self reference `this`.

Answer (score 0):

Declaring the event as following solved the problem:

```
public static event GpsUpdateHandler GpsUpdated;
```

instead of:

```
public event GpsUpdateHandler GpsUpdated;
```

In this way the Form1 event can be called static, so no new instance is necessary.